# Ошибка импортирования проекта с GitHub

Tags: intellij-idea, github

Хочу импортировать проект с гитхаба, но когда только добавил, сразу такая ошибка, кто-нибудь сталкивался?

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Ошибку лучше выкладывать текстом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читаем документацию на https://github.com/PhoenixDevTeam/Phoenix-for-VK

> Setting up enviroment: In order to build this project you need to add missing file with several VK keys.
>
> **Create** "build-config-fields.properties" file in the root of project with the following data

Этот файл **НАДО** создать самостоятельно